# Refactor ValueConverter to filter dynamically

Tags: javascript, aurelia, valueconverter, es6-module-loader

I would like to take the following ValueConverter and make it reusable for many views.

```
export class ProductFilterValueConverter {
    toView(array, value) {
        var regex = new RegExp(value, 'gi');
        var matcher = item =>
            item.abbr.match(regex) || item.name.match(regex);

        return array.filter(
            matcher
        );
    }
}
```

The filter above takes in a value from a text field and matches on either my 'abbr' column or my 'name' column.

Step 1  in refactoring to make this reusable would be to add an additional parameter that is maybe an array of strings that have the columns I would like to include in the matching OR logic.

If I pass in one value in the array like `["zip"]`, then I just want to match on my zipcode column and there would be no OR operator needed. If like in the case above I wanted to match on m,y products, maybe my array would look like: `["abbr","name"]`.

This method above or possibly having another object defined that knows all the different objects columns and we can use it as a lookup:

```
var lookup = {
    products: ["abbr","name"],
    zipcodes: ["zip"],
    offices: ["city", "state", "zipcode"]
}
```

I foresee this `ValueConverter` being used as a filter for many things in my new site. IT would be best to use it on any object, and pass a serch term as a second parameter and a list of column names to match on as a 3rd parameter and have it conditionally search with `&&` and/or `||`. Wow that last bit was confusing.

Below is my shot so far at the views html code and the js for the filter, I am struggling with how to do this:

**Data (The utilities object we are filtering)**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "utilityName": "Big Valley",
    "abbr": "Big Valley",
    "city": "Big Bear Lake"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "utilityName": "Pac Electric",
    "abbr": "PE",
    "city": "Los Angelas"
  }
]
```

**GenericFilter.js**

```
export class GenericFilterValueConverter {
    toView(array, value, cols) {

        var columns = cols;
        var matchLogic = "item => {";
        var regex = new RegExp(value, 'gi');
        //debugger;
        for (var i = 1; i <= columns.length; i++) {
            matchLogic += "item." + columns[i] + ".match(regex)";
            matchLogic += (i < columns.length) ? " || " : "";
            matchLogic += (i === columns.length ? "}" : "");
        }
        var matcher = eval(matchLogic);

        return array.filter(
            matcher
        );
    }
}
```

**view.js**

```
export class Utilities { 
    constructor(...) {
    //below the definedColumns are defined in the js module
    this.definedColumns = ["abbr","utilityName"];
}
```

**view.html**

```
<template>
    <!--<require from="./officeFilter"></require>-->
    <require from="../services/genericFilter"></require>
    <input type="text" name="searchValue" value.bind="searchValue" />
    <div class="grid" repeat.for="office of offices | genericFilter:searchValue:definedColumns">
            <!--MORE HTML HERE TO RENDER GRID-->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Currently I am not getting a JavaScript error, but my filter is no longer working either. I have zero results on my page as if the ValueConverter ran for a first time and the `array.filter` has filtered out all of the results maybe?

The idea to use eval was obviously not the greatest, and the answer I came up with below does not use evil eval!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I have came up with as I had no luck with building the logical OR statement with eval():

**GenericFilter.js**

```
    export class GenericFilterValueConverter {

    toView(array, value, cols, showResults=false) {

        if (!value) {
            return showResults ?  array :  [];
        };

        var filteredArray = array.filter(
            function(objArray) {
                for (var col in objArray) {
                    if (objArray.hasOwnProperty(col)) {
                        if (cols.indexOf(col) != -1 && objArray[col].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                };
                return false;
            });
        return filteredArray;
    }
}
```

view.html

```
<template>
    <require from="../services/genericFilter"></require>
    <input type="text" name="searchValue" value.bind="searchValue"/>
        <div  class="grid" repeat.for="utility of utilities | genericFilter:searchValue:definedColumns:true">
                <!--template repeats for each utility-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

view.js

```
 export class Utilities {
    constructor(utilityNameData, router) {
        this.data = utilityNameData;
        this.router = router;
        this.utilities = [];

        //...
        this.definedColumns = ["abbr","utilityName"];
    }
```